# Not able to color table cells in Splunk using colorPalette as per if condition written

Tags: splunk

I have JSON data (simplified example) uploaded to Splunk which looks as below :

```
{
    P1 : {
        "type":"input",
        "width": "10"
        },
    P2 : {
        "type":"output",
        "width": "20"
        }
}
```

I will fetch this data for two different years and then compare.
I will only show the current year data in table and I want to color the cells of type and width columns based on some condition. 
My query is as below where I am taking the diffs in eval variables tdiff and sdiff with if condition.

```
    index=MY_DB time IN($curYr$, $prevYr$)
    | eval raw1=if(match(time,"$curYr$"),_raw,0)
    | eval raw2=if(match(time,"$prevYr$"),_raw,0)
    | eval pin_name1=json_array_to_mv(json_keys(raw1))
    | eval pin_name1 = mvfilter(NOT match(pin_name1, "uploadedBy"))
    | mvexpand pin_name1
    | eval data = json_extract(raw1, pin_name1), type = json_extract(data, "type"), size = 
     json_extract(data, "width") 
    |eval pin_name2=json_array_to_mv(json_keys(raw2))|eval pin_name2 = mvfilter(NOT 
     match(pin_name2, "uploadedBy")  )
    | mvexpand pin_name2
    | eval data2 = json_extract(raw2, pin_name2), type2 = json_extract(data2, "type"), size2 
    = json_extract(data2, "width") 
    | eval tdiff = if(type==type2, "same","notsame")
    | eval sdiff = if(size==size2, "same","notsame")
    | table pin_name1,type, size
```

And the color palette code is as below:

```
  <format type="color" field="type">
          <colorPalette type="expression">if( match(tdiff, "same") , "#c1fa9b", "#3c4091")</colorPalette>
  </format>
  <format type="color" field="size">
          <colorPalette type="expression">if( match(sdiff, "same") , "#c1fa9b", "#3c4091")</colorPalette>
  </format>
```

But the color is not taking appropriate effect.
Please help.

Thanks